# Is this an attack on my site?

Tags: php, web-services, url, joomla

My joomla site has been restricted by my hosting. It says that there are some script that is causing high usage and send me a list of all processes that is running. 
The issue here is that in the cpanel process list I keep seeing this

```
/opt/php53/bin/php-cgi /MY-JOOMLA-ROOT/index.php
```

It keep showing this. Normally if it shows up once or twice it is ok. But today, it shows alot and when I kill the process, it comes back.

The list that my hosting gave me shows this

```
110.89.63.143 MY-DOMAIN/medical-suites&submit=%E9%94%9F%E6%96%A4%E6%8B%B7%E8%AF%A2 
110.89.63.143 MY-DOMAIN/medical-suites&submit=%E9%94%9F%E6%96%A4%E6%8B%B7%E8%AF%A2 
110.89.63.143 MY-DOMAIN/novena-medical-centre-for-sale&cid=2100040&dr=30 
110.89.63.143 MY-DOMAIN/novena-medical-centre-for-sale&cid=2100040&dr=30 
110.89.63.143 MY-DOMAIN/our-privacy-policy.html/page/5 
110.89.63.143 MY-DOMAIN/our-privacy-policy.html/page/5 
110.89.63.143 MY-DOMAIN/pandan-valley&chkall=on&googlerank=1&google=1&baidu=1&msn= 
110.89.63.143 MY-DOMAIN/pandan-valley&chkall=on&googlerank=1&google=1&baidu=1&msn=
```

The above are only some from a long list there are many more from the same IP and from another IP 91.207.7.133

I am not sure why this is so. The strange thing is that the url listed is different from the url I have. For example this

```
MY-DOMAIN/pandan-valley&chkall=on&googlerank=1&google=1&baidu=1&msn=
```

I have

```
MY-DOMAIN/pandan-valley as a valid page,
```

but not with

```
&chkall=on&googlerank=1&google=1&baidu=1&msn=
```

Many of them are like that with strange url attaching behind. I never make any changes to the site and it has been running fine all along.

Can someone advise how come this is happening and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to

- http://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_91.207.7.133 and
- http://www.stopforumspam.com/ipcheck/91.207.7.133 and
- http://spam-ip.com/lookup-772367-91.207.7.133.html

the 91.x.x.x IP is from Ukraine and associated with forum spam.

According to

- http://www.stopforumspam.com/ipcheck/110.89.63.143 and
- https://cleantalk.org/blacklists/110.89.63.143

the 110.x.x.x IP is from China and also associated with forum spam.

So chances are, those are spam bots trying to post on your Joomla site.

You can try to send eMails to the provider's abuse adresses (`whois <ip>` to get that info) or ask your hosting to to block these IPs.

Comment: Thanks for the check. Im just curious how come the hosting don't block these ips.

Comment: @user3762495 spammers change their IPs frequently, so an IP assigned to a spammer today might be assigned to an innocent user tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Most websites get hit with a lot of fake URLs in order to sniff for what the server is running.  If you go into Joomla's 301 manager, it will list all the 404s generated. You are almost certain to see "wp_admin" (the wordpress login) there, for example.

The "&chkall=on&googlerank=1&google=1&baidu=1&msn=" makes me think this particular one is crawling the site for SEO purposes, possibly looking for forms.

Depending who your site is aimed at, blocking by country would limit how many of these you get.  eg if you are not aiming at china, block china.  They seem to be responsible for a lot of spam at the moment.

Comment: Thanks you, thats a great idea, I will do just that.